# magento community - google shopping feed

Tags: magento-1.7, webshop, google-shopping-api

I have a question about Google Shopping Feed in Magento Community 1.7.0.2

Is there a good plugin which i can use to build this? Did some research through Google but I didn't get a good response. The budget is low so for free would be awesome :)

I've seen the Google Shopping API, but that one is only for Magento Connect.

Thanks for all the tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the Helloostore plugin, it's quite cheap and works allright

Answer (score 0):

Magento comes with a built in google feed builder. Is there something specific you are trying to do that you cant do with the built in feature?

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/publishing-products-to-google-content

Answer (score -1):

Try this script its not a plugin but just a single file   https://github.com/themestechnology/magento-google-merchant-center-shopping-feed-atom